# Android Studio 3.2.1 - New project fails to run

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried creating a new project on **Android Studio 3.2.1**. In the project creation wizard, choosing the minimum SDK version support as **API level 21 (Android 5.0)**, created a project with the “**Empty Activity**” template.

I tried with both with and without “Kotlin” Support with the same result. When I tried to run this newly created application on any emulator/phone, the application crashed.

However, when I changed the minSDK to anything less than 21, the application ran successfully. It was also running fine when the minSDK version was above 21.

**Note: The compileSDKVersion and targetSDKVersion was set to 28**

Here's the crash log.

```
2018-11-10 02:25:43.886 3742-3742/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.kbeanie.test1, PID: 3742
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.kbeanie.test1/com.kbeanie.test1.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.kbeanie.test1.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.kbeanie.test1-BOVWTjJJqRM5jnzV5X3nnw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.kbeanie.test1-BOVWTjJJqRM5jnzV5X3nnw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.kbeanie.test1.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.kbeanie.test1-BOVWTjJJqRM5jnzV5X3nnw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.kbeanie.test1-BOVWTjJJqRM5jnzV5X3nnw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1174)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity;
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
            ... 12 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 15 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;
            ... 15 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 15 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/app/SupportActivity;
            ... 15 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 15 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleOwner;
            ... 15 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.kbeanie.test1-BOVWTjJJqRM5jnzV5X3nnw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.kbeanie.test1-BOVWTjJJqRM5jnzV5X3nnw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 15 more
```

Here's the build.gradle file contents.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kbeanie.test2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide gradle files from your project. So actually the problem is hidden but 90% it is because of some issues with gradle and dependency collisions.

Comment: I also faced same issue.